# What have I done wrong to render circle with mid point theoram using opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math, glad

I am not able to render circle with my following programme ,unable to detect problem in  my code . This code compiles fine and runs but does not show the required output

This is the output:

[image]

In This code firstly initialization takes place using glfw
then shaders are defined and uniform projection matrix is set up accordingly
then rendering loop begins in which `midPointCircleAlgo` function is called which does the
rendering , further plot function displays output on screen .
Where am I going wrong .

This is vertex shader: -

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 apos;
uniform mat4 projection;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection*vec4(apos,0.0,1.0);
}
```

```cpp
#include <glad/glad.h> 
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height); 
void plot(int x, int y);
void midPointCircleAlgo(int r);

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,3 );
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"Circle",NULL,NULL);
    if(!window){
        std::cout << "Failed to open window";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glViewport(0,0,800,600);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window,framebuffer_size_callback);

    Shader shader("shader.vs","shader.fs");//I use a header file containing shader abstraction
    glm::mat4 projection;
    projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    int pmatrix = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "projection");
    shader.use();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(pmatrix,1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(projection));

    int r = 10;

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //render Circle
        shader.use();
        midPointCircleAlgo(10);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();    
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window,int width,int height){
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);   
}



void midPointCircleAlgo(int r)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = r;
    float decision = 5 / 4 - r;
    plot(x, y);

    while (y > x)
    {
        if (decision < 0)
        {
            x++;
            decision += 2 * x + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            y--;
            x++;
            decision += 2 * (x - y) + 1;
        }
        plot(x, y);
        plot(x, -y);
        plot(-x, y);
        plot(-x, -y);
        plot(y, x);
        plot(-y, x);
        plot(y, -x);
        plot(-y, -x);
    }

}

void plot(int x,int y) 
{
    int vertices[] = { x,y};
    unsigned int VBO,VAO;
    glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_INT, GL_TRUE, 0, (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);   
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 2);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is the orthographic projection.

> ```
> projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
> ```

Since your geometry is drawn at a z-coordinate of 0.0, it is clipped by the near plane of the projection (0.1). The circle is drawn around (0, 0), so you should choose a projection which keeps the center in the center of the viewport:

```cpp
projection = glm::ortho(-400.0f, 400.0f, -300.0f, 300.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

When you use [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)

> ```
> glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_INT, GL_TRUE, 0, (void *)0);
> ```

then, the 4th parameter specifies whether fixed-point data values should be normalized (`GL_TRUE`) or converted directly as fixed-point values (`GL_FALSE`). This means, if the parameter is `GL_TRUE`, then the value in the range of the data type `int` are mapped to floating point values in the range [-1.0, 1.0]. You wan to convert the integral values 1:1 to flation point values, so the parameter has to be `GL_FALSE`:

```cpp
 glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);
```

---

Note, alternatively you can use [`glVertexAttribIPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) (focus on **`I`**), which is for integral vertex shader input attributes:

```cpp
glVertexAttribIPointer(0, 2, GL_INT, 0, (void *)0);
```

Of course, then the data type of the attribute in the vertex shader has to be `ivec2` rather than `vec2`:

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in ivec2 apos;

uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{ 
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(vec2(apos), 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

---

The idea of a buffer is to stor as many data as possible in the buffer and then render all the vertices at once.
But even if you want to draw a single point, it is a bad idea to create a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) and a [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) for each point and to destroy it immediately after the drawing.

Create an empty buffer and and a vertex array object at initialization, before the main loop:

```c
unsigned int VBO, VAO;

int main() {

    // [...]

    glGenVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2*sizeof(int), 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);
    //glVertexAttribIPointer(0, 2, GL_INT, 0, (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // [...]
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Use [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) to init/change the content of the buffer objects data store, before drawing the point:

```c
void plot(int x, int y) 
{
    int vertices[] = {x, y};

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
}
```

Side note, the 3rd parameter of [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) is the number of vertex coordinates, but not the number of elements in the array. The tuple size number of components per coordinate) is set in the vertex attribute specification.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Circle now rendered successfully but changing the radius of circle has no effect on display . Circle remains the same . What is the problem ?

Comment: now the circle is little larger on display but changing radius has still no effect

Comment: @user7695301 Sorry I've overlooked that. Of course `midPointCircleAlgo(r);` rather than `midPointCircleAlgo(10);`